# Python Flask Jinja2 template null error

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Im trying to do just basic whois application with Flask + pycharm and everything goes well in pycharm. It prints all whois info pycharm's console, but when I launch the app in local server or deployment server jinja2 output's: 0 instead of whois info. Any help:

```
domain = os.system('whois %s' % form.domain.data)
return render_template('home.html', form=form, domain=domain)
```

Here is the template:

```
   {{ domain }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are confused between return status and output display. os.system returns 0 since it ran successfully. When you run it on the command line, what you see is the output and not the return status. You can use open and retrieve the output as:

```
import subprocess as sp
p = sp.Popen('os.system('whois %s' % form.domain.data)',stdout=sp.PIPE,stderr=sp.PIPE)
domain, errors = p.communicate()
return render_template('home.html', form=form, domain=domain)
```

Comment: Little typo you have there. I was assuming that i need to stdout something, but didnt know how. After that snippet I have some iteration error.